# Firebase Authentication get mobile app users

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

How to export users who have downloaded the mobile apps?

Firebase can export the list of Authenticated users but there seems to be no built-in way to get the users who have downloaded the mobile apps:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

-- My specific use case --
I want to give a free purchase ticket only to the first 5000 +- users who have downloaded the apps.

Comment: You could set a flag on a users profile as long as the user collection size is below 5000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication has no built-in way to track from what platform a user accesses your app.

The closest I can think of is to set the user's ID in Google Analytics for Firebase, and track the platform there.

The alternative would be (as Joshua commented) to have the native apps write a for for each user to a database (like the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore). If you choose this approach, you'll have to find a way to secure that write though. Here too Firebase doesn't have anything built in to only allow writes from certain platforms, so it's up to you to come up with a security scheme.